# PNP Provisioning Schema for adding content type to the Existing List

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

we require a pnp provisioning template to add content type to the existing list,
i also found some weird thing happening when I added

```
 EnableFolders="False" in the List instance schema
```

The content type added to the list previously was getting removed,

can any body help on the same

Answer (score 0):

```
EnableFolders="FALSE"
```

is to allowed the creation of Folders, for ContentTypes, try :

```
ContentTypesEnabled="TRUE"
```